# not sure why nodemailer isnt working properly

Tags: node.js, express

Not sure why this isnt working properly. i think the configuration looks right but I keep getting this error :getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND smpt.mydomian.com

```
       let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: "smtp.mydomain.com",
      port: 465,
      secure: true,
      auth: {
         user: "abc@mydomain.com",
         pass: "password",
      },
      
   });

   let mailOptions = {
      from: email,
      to: "abc@domail.com",
      subject: `New Lead ${fullName}`,
      text: newMail,
   };

   // step 3
   transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
         console.log("there is an error " + err);
      } else {
         console.log("mail sent successfully");
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: Does such an smtp host really exist?

Comment: @Mureinik thanks for the heads up! Honestly I didnt know what smpt was. I removed it and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion its better to create a class for that just like this

```
  class Mailer {
   sendMail = async (emailAddress) => {
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: "gmail",
      auth: {
        user: testUser,
        pass: testPass,
      },
    });

    const option = {
      from: `${EMAIL_ADDRESS}`,
      to: emailAddress,
      subject: "test Subject",
      text: "Test text",
    };

    await transporter.sendMail(option, (err, info) => {
      if (!err) {
        console.log(`Email sent Successfully ... !`.green.underline.bold);
        return true;
      } else {
        console.log(
          `We have problem while sendil Email ... !`.red.underline.bold
        );
        return false;
      }
    });
  };
}
```

i hope this class help you